# python: for short_list in long_list

Tags: python

I have a long list with `N` elements. I would like to iterate the long list, but picking  `K` elements at every iteration (or less if there are less than `K` in the long list). What would be the most elegant way to do it?

```
for short_list_K in long_list_N:
    # len(short_list_K) <= K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html) module documentation provides this recipe:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Which can be used like so:

```
for short_list in grouper(K, long_list):
      # blah
```

Comment: It would help to point out that it's `izip_longest` in 2.x and `zip_longest` in 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Grouper Idiom](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
In [1]: a = range(10)

In [2]: import itertools

In [3]: list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(a)] * 3))
Out[3]: [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, None, None)]
```

Comment: It would help to point out that it's izip_longest in 2.x and zip_longest in 3.x